# How detect contact on a line in SpriteKit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, collision

i have a transparent line at top of my scene in SpriteKit . nodes can pass over it with no collision (but contact occurs) .
i create a thin rectangle instead of line , but when a node contact with this rectangle the behavior of node changes completely(it is strange) .
where is the problem ?

```
CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 2);

            SKShapeNode *yourline = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];   



            yourline.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:rectangle.size];
            yourline.fillColor =[SKColor redColor];
            yourline.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = topEdgeCategory;

            yourline.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
            yourline.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2,self.frame.size.height-3);
            yourline.physicsBody.friction = 0;
            yourline.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0;
            yourline.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0f;               

            [self addChild:yourline];


    self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = edgeCategory;        

    // change gravity settings of the physics world
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
```

you can suppose that i want to create a linear laser that when a node contact to it , its health decreases .
other question : how can i coloring the shape ? in my scene it is transparent , though the color is RED .

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please include the implementation of the contact delegate as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough info to answer the first question, but I can answer the second. 
You need to change:

```
SKShapeNode *yourline = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];
```

to:

```
SKShapeNode *yourline = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithRectOfSize:rectangle.size];
```

Now you will be able to see the red line. The problem before was that you never laid out the size of "yourline" you only initialized it. The actual node and its physics body can be different sizes, so they must both be specified. You only stated the size of the physics body. Hope this helps!

Comment: Did this solution work for you? If not, what's wrong with it?

Comment: no , there is no no function named "shapeNodeWithRectOfSize" . i just set the "path" of SKShapeNode and then set the collisionBitMask = 0 . now it works .

Comment: Huh, that worked for me. What version of xcode are you using?